# SQL Query to select most popular data from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select the most popular name from this table which is **Peter**

How can I do this? I have tried different SQL query but none worked.

```
SQL> select * from OurStaffs;

   SID S_LOCATION S_SITE  S_RAN S_NAME
------ ---------- ------- ----- ----------
     1 hotel      root1   rank1 Peter
     2 barbeach   root3   rank0 John
     3 island     root2   rank2 peter
     4 hotel      root2   rank0 ujah
```

11 rows selected.

Comment: why is peter the mos popular name?

Comment: @roberto: Look at the poster's name, and you'll have a clue.

Comment: Please i need a help, you can add your name in the answer as popular name

Comment: What if two or more names are the most popular?

Answer (score 2):

If you're case-sensitive, then something like:

```
SELECT
   S_NAME,
   count() AS cnt 
FROM
   OurStaffs 
GROUP BY
   S_NAME 
ORDER BY
   cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to be case-insensitive, replace S_NAME with something like `tolower(S_NAME)` or `lower(S_NAME)` etc, depending on the DBMS you're using. For Oracle, it should be:

```
SELECT
   lower(S_NAME),
   count() AS cnt 
FROM
   OurStaffs 
GROUP BY
   lower(S_NAME)
ORDER BY
   cnt DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

<sub>(You'd get the same result with `upper()` of course.)</sub>

Comment: SqlPlus - that's probably oracle

Comment: By default use `asc` sort and result for this query is less popular name. Also need use `upper/lower` function because `peter` and `Peter` different names for query

Comment: @HAYMbl4: You're right, sorry. And I don't need the inner query either.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed SQL Plus with Oracle.. Try this out - it also accounts for case sensitivity.

```
With OurStaffs AS
(
      Select 1 SID , 'hotel' S_LOCATION, 'root1' S_SITE, 'rank1' S_RAN, 'Peter' S_NAME From Dual
Union Select 2, 'barbeach', 'root3', 'rank0', 'John' From Dual
Union Select 3, 'island', 'root2', 'rank2', 'peter' From Dual
Union Select 4, 'hotel', 'root2', 'rank0', 'ujah' From Dual
)

Select *
From
(
  Select Upper (S_Name) S_Name, Count(*)
  From OurStaffs
  Group By Upper (S_Name)
  Order by 2 Desc
)x
Where RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the name and then order by the count. Here's an example:

```
SELECT
   S_NAME
FROM
    OurStaffs
GROUP BY
    S_NAME
ORDER BY
    COUNT(S_NAME) DESC
LIMIT 1
```